# What is the approximate timeline of season 6 of Game of Thrones?

Tags: game-of-thrones, time

Events in *Game of Thrones* season 6 have proceeded with rather uneven timing:

> - Theon leaves Sansa somewhere near Castle Black in episode 2 and reaches the Iron Islands in episode 4.
> - The Greyjoys flee the Iron Islands in episode 5 and reach Volantis in episode 7 and Meereen in episode 9.
> - Littlefinger gets Robert Arryn's approval in episode 4 and reaches Winterfell in episode 9 (travelling overland, that might be excusable compared to the Greyjoys' speed).
> - Sam leaves the Tarleys in episode 6 and reaches Oldtown in episode 10 — similar to Littlefinger above, *but* Hornhill is apparently around the south of the Reach, just like Oldtown (and seems to be closer to Oldtown than the Twins are to King's Landing).
> - Daenerys is in Vaes Dothrak in episode 4, somewhere else in episode 6, and in Meereen in episode 9.
> - An unknown number of ships are repaired between episode 9 and 10.

Episode 9 is perhaps excusable, since it is tightly focused. But the last episode is particularly egregious:

> - Arya leaves Braavos in episode 8 and is in the Twins by episode 10, at the same time as Ser Jaime, who was in Riverrun in episode 8.
> - Sam sees the white ravens leaving Oldtown, and they reach Winterfell the same episode — no one mentions white ravens in Kings Landing, though I suspect that's because greater events are unfolding there.
> - Ser Jaime leaves the Twins and reaches Kings Landing.
> - Lord Varys is at Dorne, having left Meereen in episode 8, and later on *back at Meereen*.

Can anyone tell me what the approximate timeline of season 6 is? I'm especially interested in the time gaps between various events, and whether events happening in the same episode happened at approximately the same time.

Comment: Short answer.... no! :P

Comment: @Skooba I'm afraid of that, but better minds than mine give a lot more attention to GoT than I do; someone somewhere must have pieced together a timeline. :)

Comment: Yeah the time is notorious for being all over the place. I know the last two books were taking place at the same but separated due to geography. That could help explain some of the jumping.

Comment: An underlying question is, "are events seen in the same episode occurring concurrently?" I don't think we can even assume that - it's rare that characters directly acknowledge another storyline in progress in another part of the world, so it may just be that the stories are not on the same timeline. e.g. Varys' visit may have taken place weeks or months before the other events of episode 10.

Comment: If you also consider the trip of Sam from the wall and what else has happened since Sam left the wall then Sam was either a very slow traveler or everyone else very fast. With all these story lines existing there is bound to happen some inconsistencies with the time line. They really screwed things up in my opinion

Comment: Even more strangely, Dany's fleet at the end of episode 10 appears to have some _Dornish ships_ in it. It's not entirely clear whether those ships sailed all the way from Dorne to Meereen offscreen (only to sail straight back again), or if the fleet has already completed a significant fraction of its journey to Westeros by the time the Dornish ships join them.

Comment: I've always suspected that each story is written independently from the others, then all are shuffled together to make a book.  Occasionally a few lines are written based on how they were shuffled together but otherwise it's just a shuffle.

Answer (score 2):

Time is not constant between different scenes in any particular episode.  The various stories are not told at the same pace.  In any given episode, scenes with Bran north of the Wall might take a few hours, while a week or more passes in scenes in King's Landing.

From writer and producer [Bryan Cogman](http://winteriscoming.net/2016/06/09/game-of-thrones-writer-explains-how-characters-travel-so-quickly/):

> The timelines between the various storylines don’t necessarily line up within a given episode. For instance, the ‘Northern Tour’ Jon and Sansa embark on would probably take a couple weeks, but Arya’s storyline over the past few episodes only spans a few days. We realized a while ago that if we tied ourselves in knots trying to make all the ‘story days’ line up between all the characters the momentum would suffer.